# Does it ever make sense to have two concurrent sessions in the same browser?

Tags: session, browser, concurrency

I was wondering if it ever would make sense to have two concurrent sessions in the same browser? There could be two types of cases with this:

1) A user opens a browser window and logs in as user A, starting session 1. Then he opens another browser window (in the same browser) where he logs in as user A, but starts a different session, session 2.

I know that this is often not possible in many browsers, as one session cookie is set for the entire browser. However, in some browsers, it is possible to have multiple sessions in that manner.

2) This is similar to 1, except that the second time the user logs in, he logs in as user B, starting session 2. So now you have a person logged in as two users in the same browser.

Finally, allowing these things doesn't seem like the best security practice and neither does it seem to be practical. What do others think?

Comment: Please tell us the name of the browser to be able to achieve (1).

Comment: @EdHeal - any browser that supports private browsing allows (1). IE, FF, Chrome, etc.

Comment: @chuex - My understanding is that you cannot have two tabs in FF that has a different cookie (i.e. session) for each of them for a particular site. Private browsing just means that certain information is not stored after you have closed down the browser.

Comment: @EdHeal - log into SO with FF. Then start a private session. In the private session, go to SO. You'll see that you are not logged in with that browser. Log in. You now have two sessions. Obviously if you close the private browser session, there will be no record (history) of it.

Comment: So do you think it would be a good idea to provide support for this? That is, allowing someone to log in as multiple users into my website in the same browser?

Answer (score 2):

First thing First as the your Assumption is wrong. First of all you have to understand that when Single website is accessed from browser have single session and its not possible to simultaneously run different session of same web Browser.

It seems you have wrongly understand the working of Private Browser. Private Session are not made not to share information cookies and data with other public session and vise versa also. As soon as you close the Private Session all the Cache, Cookie and other things are deleted for forever.

I have not seen any web browser supporting the Multiple session of browser.

But an alternative approach is available i.e you have to create different Web Browser Profiles which can help you as each Profile data is maintained separately and have no conflict with other sessions.

Comment: In the old days, it was certainly possible. Do you think it is a good idea to provide support for multiple concurrent sessions in a browser, just in case? Or do you think that for security and practical reasons, it's not a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

One possible scenario currently I am facing requires allowing multiple user sessions from the same browser and I have not been able to find a proper solution for it yet.

We are using Yii framework. Currently we have two kinds of users i.e customers and admins. Both login from the same login form and use same session name and variables to store session information. Only based on type column in user table(customer or admin), the user is taken to appropriate views. In one of admin views(pages), there is an option for admin to log in as any of the users and propagate through the user's view in an iframe. The problem is that when the admin open two tabs and logs in as two different users, the session information of one overwrites the other and we start getting session related issues.

Can anyone suggest me a proper way to handle these kind of issues. I have searched a lot on trying to handle this with multiple sessions, but have not been able to find a proper solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing to "provide support for" here. One browser cannot hold more than one session, since it only holds one unique cookie per site, regardless of window. *If* a browser actually has a mode in which it supports holding two separate identical cookies per site, then it's the same as if the user logged on from another browser or another machine. *That* certainly should work; i.e. you should not try to subvert that behavior. A double session inside the same browser is then just a specific instance of this multi-session behavior, nothing special.